# jQuery mobile dynamically add elements

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a [list view](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) to a jQuery mobile site after the site has been loaded. Merely adding it to the DOM doesn't work because it doesn't parse it for data-role tags once it has been loaded. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/h2gfT/2/

My question is, how do I refresh it? I've found numerous similar questions with answers ranging from using .refresh (which doesn't work because the element is never initialized as a list view) to .page (which doesn't work at all and I have no idea why). I am using the latest version of jQuery mobile at the time of writing, **1.02b**.

Thanks.

Comment: What is that not working in your fiddle example?

Comment: It's not being converted to a jQm list. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `.listview()` on your element.

```
$("ul").listview();
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/h2gfT/4/)**

Comment: Looks like the jquery.mobile API for v1.4 requires the "refresh" command mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `data-role` attribute from page to make it work. I think that was the issue in your markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/h2gfT/3/

Comment: Yes. Now explain that one to me. You removed the `data-role` attribute from the page?

Comment: Yes, I removed that `data-role` attribute from page.

Comment: That answer and comment aren't useful. They don't explain anything.

Comment: Because it doesn't really work. I think what this solution does is to take an already rendered listview and just move it somewhere else in the page. You could use that to your advantage by precreating these views else where and moving them around later, but of course this solution is very limiting in its scope

Answer (score 0):

I like to call the jQuery trigger method to accomplish this:

`$(element).trigger("create")`

So far it works for me without a hitch although I have heard it reported that creating new pages with this can be problematic.